# Pace Maker in Select statement not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, pacemaker

Select statement in sqlite3(Python) without pacemaker is working fine but is behaving odd with the pacemaker(?)

In the below code when I'm using "table_column_name" in the select I am getting all the items in my list populated in my list box. but when I am passing it as tuple to select statement with the help of pacemaker my list bosx has only one entry i.e "table_column_name".

```
class ListObj(tkinter.Listbox):

    def __init__(self, window, cname, r, c, rs, cs, sticky, bg, 
                     padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=0, ipady=0, **kwargs):

        self = tkinter.Listbox(window)

        self.grid(row=r, column=c, rowspan=rs, columnspan=cs, 
                  sticky=sticky, padx=padx, pady=pady,
                  ipadx=ipadx, ipady=ipady)

        List = cursor.execute(f"SELECT DISTINCT ? FROM juke_box", 
                              (cname,))

        for x in List:
            print(x)
            self.insert(tkinter.END, x)


    list_box= ListObj(root, 'table_column_name',1,0,2,1,'nsew', 'sky blue')
```

my expected outcome is that I should get all the items in the column name passed as tuple should populate in the tk list.

Comment: nothing in your code uses pacemaker as far as I can see. What relevance has it for an sql-query? how does it help us reproduce your error as a [mcve] should?

Answer (score 0):

```
List = cursor.execute(f"SELECT DISTINCT ? FROM juke_box", 
                          (cname,))
```

Looks like you're trying to pass a column name as a bound parameter. You can't do that; table and column names have to be present in the SQL statement when it's compiled, not passed at execution time. The `cname` variable is being bound as a string, and that string returned. Because it's a `SELECT DISTINCT`, and every row of the table ends up selecting the same `'table_column_name'` string, only one row with that value is being returned. That whole query basically can be reduced to `SELECT ?` where the question mark is replaced by the string in `cname`.